Script to create folders and subfolders and their subfolders shows an error
I'm attempting to create a 5 level folder having an Excel sheet as the source.
NOTE: Excel sheet is column organized by levels on each column as shown.
Reference VB script from:
https://superuser.com/questions/799666/creating-folders-and-sub-folders-with-a-vba-macro
ERR: **'Shell ("cmd /c md " & Chr(34) & strFolders & Chr(34))**
Script:
Sub CreateFolderStructure()
    Dim objRow As Range, objCell As Range, strFolders As String

    For Each objRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        strFolders = "C:\Users\morar\Downloads\FoldersNSubsr"
        
        For Each objCell In objRow.Cells
            strFolders = strFolders & "\" & objCell
        Next
           **Shell ("cmd /c md " & Chr(34) & strFolders & Chr(34))**
    Next
End Sub

I haven't found any solution yet.

"an error" doesn't tell us much about what's going wrong when you run your code.  Swap out that /c for /k in the Shell call, and see if you can get more info on the problem.

Without Shell:
Sub CreateFolderStructure()
    Const ROOT_DIR As String = "C:\Temp"
    
    Dim objRow As Range, c As Range, strFolders As String, v

    For Each objRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        strFolders = ROOT_DIR
        
        For Each c In objRow.Cells
            v = Trim(c.Value)
            If Len(v) > 0 Then
                strFolders = strFolders & "\" & v
                'do we need to create this folder?
                If Dir(strFolders, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
                    Debug.Print "Creating: " & strFolders
                    MkDir strFolders
                Else
                    Debug.Print "Exists: " & strFolders
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Next objRow
End Sub

